# seaborn clustermap requires scipy to be available

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm trying to run the following cell in my notebook yet it fails requesting scipy even though it is installed and imported in the venv

```
import seaborn as sn
import scipy
sn.clustermap(data)
```

the error thrown is

```
venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py:1250, in clustermap(data, pivot_kws, method, metric, z_score, standard_scale, figsize, cbar_kws, row_cluster, col_cluster, row_linkage, col_linkage, row_colors, col_colors, mask, dendrogram_ratio, colors_ratio, cbar_pos, tree_kws, **kwargs)
   1157 """
   1158 Plot a matrix dataset as a hierarchically-clustered heatmap.
   1159 
   (...)
   1247 
   1248 """
   1249 if _no_scipy:
-> 1250     raise RuntimeError("clustermap requires scipy to be available")
   1252 plotter = ClusterGrid(data, pivot_kws=pivot_kws, figsize=figsize,
   1253                       row_colors=row_colors, col_colors=col_colors,
   1254                       z_score=z_score, standard_scale=standard_scale,
   1255                       mask=mask, dendrogram_ratio=dendrogram_ratio,
   1256                       colors_ratio=colors_ratio, cbar_pos=cbar_pos)
   1258 return plotter.plot(metric=metric, method=method,
   1259                     colorbar_kws=cbar_kws,
   1260                     row_cluster=row_cluster, col_cluster=col_cluster,
   1261                     row_linkage=row_linkage, col_linkage=col_linkage,
   1262                     tree_kws=tree_kws, **kwargs)

RuntimeError: clustermap requires scipy to be available
```

Comment: How did you start your notebook?

Comment: It's running the jupyter server through pycharm

Comment: I'm not sure how that works, but I wouldn't be surprised if it starts with `jupyter notebook`; but also, that jupyter is *not* installed in your v-env, and thus jupyter can't find scipy (since it doesn't know about your v-env).

Comment: See if you can find a setting in PyCharm that tells PyCharm how to start the notebook server. Let us know what you find.

Comment: All I've been able to find is that it uses Managed Server configured with a path to python executable and the port is dynamic

Comment: Is the path to that Python executable the one that is used for your virtual environment?

Comment: Yes, also `!pip install jupyter` claims that the jupyter package is installed

Comment: And `!pip list` shows scipy in the output as well?

Comment: yes, scipy is installed as well

Comment: Just to be clear about the error: could you add the (full) error message to your question?

Comment: So `import scipy` doesn't fail! But the call to `seaborn.clustermap` does. What about a single `import scipy.cluster`?

Comment: Executes without any problems

Comment: Can you try `import seaborn; print(seaborn.__file__)` And then `import scipy.cluster; print(scipy.cluster.__file__)`?

Answer (score 0):

You could reinstall scipy (in your virtual enviroment) and reopen your code editor (I use Jupyter in VS), that worked for me.

```
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
import scipy
```